# React Native how to revert back to development mode after publishing the app

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I just submitted my ios app to the app store (built using react-native). As I had to move the app to release, I had to make some changes in Xcode, like disable ATS, debugging mode etc, I have made a lot of changes. Now I want work on the next update but I am not sure how I can revert back all the options I have changed. Can someone please tell me how I can do this?

Comment: Isn't your code versioned?

Comment: I have the same issue. The below answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There are only simple 2 steps:

1. Change scheme release to debug :
   to change scheme Just goto `Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme`
   and change build configuration to **Debug**
2. In `AppDelegate.m` change `jsCodeLocation` path.
   that is

   ```
   //this is for release scheme

   jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];

   //this is for debug scheme

   jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

   //this is what you want
   ```

Comment: this worked for me; there was a bit of a lag in it initial loading from localhost. You might also need to add a local host exception for ATS by adding it to NSExceptionDomains in Info.plist (e.g., reverse #1 here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html)